# Selection Handler of Google annotated timeline

Tags: event-handling, google-visualization

In my Annotated timeline there is no annotation only data points. But I need to listen to the click events and need to know the date of the point where the user is clicking. How can I achieve this. In Google's JAVA API there is a select handler

```
addSelectHandler(new SelectHandler()
  {
   @Override
   public void onSelect(SelectEvent event) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    Window.alert("Date selected");
    searchCriteria.setDate(StaticUtil.setTimeZero(DataWareHouse.marketInfo.getValueDate(getSelections().get(0).getRow(), 0)));
    searchEvent.setSearchCriteria(searchCriteria);
    eventBus.fireEvent(searchEvent);

   }
  });
```

But its not working here.
And from this [JS API doc](http://code.google.com/apis/visualization/documentation/gallery/annotatedtimeline.html#Events) it seems that selectHandler only works on Annotations Markers. But I am not sure. Please share your experience on this regard.

Answer (score 1):

There is no such event, see the complete list here:
http://code.google.com/apis/chart/interactive/docs/gallery/annotatedtimeline.html#Events

The 'select' event is only for clicks on annotations but unfortunately not for points in the chart.

I assume Google is aware that many people look for this enhancement:
http://groups.google.com/group/google-visualization-api/search?q=click+event+annotated

I would love to have this as well :)

Comment: Now I am using dummy **Annotation Markers** for each point. :( Lets see what comes from Google.